# How to construction a division ring from the given field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, division-algebras

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic 2. How could we construct a division ring $D$ which centre is $F$.

Where division ring mean non-commutative ring with unity $1$ and for each non-zero element $x \in D$ there exists  $x^{-1} \in D$ such that  $xx^{-1}=x^{-1}x=1$.

Comment: What about taking $D$ a quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: I think that your "quaternionic" algebra will be (disappointingly) commutative by little Wedderburn.